# winDBG command to list objects in GC generation wise

Tags: .net, memory-management, windbg

Is there any command in winDBG(with SOS extension loaded) to list the objects by Garbage collection generation in a .NET process dump.
Basically want to see the list of objects in Generation 1.

The close command which I know "!EEHeap -gc" displays the each GC generation's start address.

Comment: http://dotnetdebug.net/2006/12/12/dumpheap-gen-in-net-20-sos-that-ships-with-the-framework/

Comment: Or `!sosex.dumpgen [GEN]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the comments of [@Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) and [@Steve Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269097/steve-johnson) answer the question.

You can either use `!eeheap -gc` to get the start and end addresses and then continue with `!dumpheap <start> <end>`. This process might need repetition for all the GC heaps if you have many.

Or you can download [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/) and use `!dumpgen 1`